# Sum the elements of an array key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, php-5.4

This is my array

```
[Company] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-28
                    [revenue] => 55
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-28
                    [revenue] => 101
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-29
                    [revenue] => 55
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-29
                    [revenue] => 101
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-30
                    [revenue] => 60
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-30
                    [revenue] => 60
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-31
                    [revenue] => 29
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2016-05-31
                    [revenue] => 60
                )

)
```

I need it to be summed up like this

```
[Company] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
         (
           [date] => 2016-05-28
           [revenue] => 151
         )
         *
         *etc.
)
```

I've tried various methods by in vain. I've tried the below method but didn't work quite well

```
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $row) {


            $res[$key][$row['date']] += $row['revenue'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of this method I've tried with?

Comment: just answered this question here. Could be easliy adapted for your needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675819/php-sum-up-array-entries-where-two-keys-have-the-same-value/37676521#37676521

Comment: Another question: is your array always sorted by date?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos yes

Comment: @atoms taking cue from ur answer, why there's an error of undefined index if I dynamically set the key of an array like this $aSortedArray[$aArray['source']][] = array( 
            'target' => $aArray['target'], 
            'total_volume' => $aArray['total_volume']
            );

Comment: setting it as `$aSortedArray[ $aArray['source'] ][] ` would nessicitate that a key with the same value as `$aArray['source']` already exists. Setting it as; `$aSortedArray[][ $aArray['source'] ] ` would create a new key with the value of $aArray['source']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, its not ideal as your looping over each array twice, as the array gets larger this will exponentially slow down.

```
$aStartingArray = array();
$aSortedArray   = array();

$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-28', 'revenue' => 55);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-28', 'revenue' => 101);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-29', 'revenue' => 55);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-29', 'revenue' => 101);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-30', 'revenue' => 60);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-30', 'revenue' => 60);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-31', 'revenue' => 29);
$aStartingArray[] = array('date'=>'2016-05-31', 'revenue' => 60);

// loop through the initial array
foreach ($aStartingArray as $aArray) {

    // set flag to reference if its been dealt with
    $bSet = false;

    // foreach of the sorted values, check if the date matches an entry
    foreach ($aSortedArray as $iPos => $aTempSortedArray) {

        if( $aTempSortedArray['date'] == $aArray['date'] ){

            // match found, add revenue
            $aSortedArray[$iPos]['revenue'] += $aArray['revenue'];

            // set flag to illustrate a dealt with row
            $bSet = true;
        }

    }

    // if still hasnt been dealt with, go add it to the array
    if(!$bSet){
        $aSortedArray[] = array( 'date' => $aArray['date'], 'revenue' => $aArray['revenue'] );
    }

}

var_dump($aSortedArray);
```

Comment: thanks for the kind words. There are much better and more efficient methods out there. Just be careful if your planning to use it for large data sets

Answer (score 1):

I have No doutes with @atoms answer,
but it will be done in one foreach

```
     $newArr = array();
     foreach($arr['Company'] as $key => $value) {
        if(isset($newArr[$value['date']])){
            $newArr[$value['date']]['revenue'] = $newArr[$value['date']]['revenue'] + $value['revenue'];
        } else {
            $newArr[$value['date']] = $value;
        }
    }
    $newArr = array_values($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$revenue_sum=0;
$elements_sum=0;
   foreach($data as $key => $value) { // 1st dimension
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) { // 2nd dimension
            if ($key2 == "revenue") {
                 $revenue_sum += $value2;
            }
            $elements_sum++;
        }
    }

 echo "Revenue sum: ".$total_sum;
 echo "Elements sum: ".$elements_sum;
```