Group 2d Laravel collection by two columns and sum a third column within each group
I have this collection:
$stocks = collect(
    [
        ['sku' => '123', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 1],
        ['sku' => '1233', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 2],
        ['sku' => '123', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 3],
        ['sku' => '5', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 4],
    ]
);

And I need get in output collection like this:
[
        ['sku' => '123', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 4],
        ['sku' => '1233', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 2],
        ['sku' => '5', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 4],
    ]

I'm grouping collection with
$coll = $coll
    ->groupBy(['sku','batch'], true)

But I don't understand how I must sum next.

Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675819/php-sum-up-array-entries-where-two-keys-have-the-same-value

yes, but i want do this with laravel collection methods

Does this answer your question? Laravel Collection with groupby, count and sum

Feeding a 2-element array to the groupBy() method only makes more work/handling because it generates an unnecessarily deep structure.  Notice how Mohammad's snippet has to reindex (values()), then call first(), then first() again just to traverse to the desired level.
Instead, feed groupBy() a callback function to form a "composite string key" and keep the grouped data shallow.
Code: (PHPize Demo)
var_export(
    $stocks
    ->groupBy(fn($row) => $row['sku'] . '_' . $row['batch'])
    ->map(fn($set) => array_merge($set->first(), ['qty_total' => $set->sum('qty_total')]))
    ->values()
    ->toArray()
);

Output:
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sku' => '123',
    'batch' => '123',
    'qty_total' => 4,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sku' => '1233',
    'batch' => '123',
    'qty_total' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'sku' => '5',
    'batch' => '123',
    'qty_total' => 4,
  ),
)

Topically related content:

Laravel Collection group by one column and sum another column within each group
Laravel Collection with groupby, count and sum
Get sum of a certain column value per group from a Laravel collection containing grouped collections
Group and sum Laravel collection data by date value of a datetime column


Yeah! This solution works for groupBy more than two keys!

You can do it like this :
  $stocks = collect(
   [
      ['sku' => '123', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 1],
      ['sku' => '1233', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 2],
      ['sku' => '123', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 3],
      ['sku' => '5', 'batch' => '123', 'qty_total' => 4],
   ]
  );

return $stocks->groupBy(['sku','batch'], true)->map(function($items){
  $firstItem = $items->values()->first();

  return collect($firstItem->first())->merge([
    'qty_total' => $firstItem->sum('qty_total')
  ]);
})->values();


There's one mistake, though, if I still have the key manufacturing_date code will work not correctly.

Sorry for that, show me the new input please and what the issue is, I will try to help you.

I need do this and group for dynamic groupBy array, it can be more than two elements for grouping.

Here is it with manufacturing_date https://3v4l.org/bVqEN6
